# How to change format of texture at runtime in unity3d

Tags: format, unity-game-engine, texture2d

**I need to change the color of the texture at runtime.**

The initial idea is according to the original texture of each pixel RGB values to calculate their own HSL, then change the H value and then calculate the corresponding RGB values.But in the use GetPixels () to obtain the original texture of the RGB values, pop-up prompts "Unsupported texture format - needs to be ARGB32, RGBA32, BGRA32, RGB24, Alpha8 or DXT", and **my problem is although I can set the format in the import Settings, but the format of the texture size is very big, obviously not suitable for generating atlas.** So I want to change format of texture from automatic compressed to argb32 or others at runtime. But I couldn't find the corresponding method.

So, any ideas ? thanks advance